# Calling a function from a string in Python throws error

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7

I am trying to call a function from a string in Python as explained in 
[Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and the Python interpreter throws an error:
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

```
def current(self, t):
    if self.iMode == None:
        return self.i
    else:
        return getattr(self, 'iMode')(t)
```

The error refers to the last line. `iMode` has been set to `sinx(t)`, that has been declared in the class.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you post the part of the declaration?

Comment: Maybe you should assign `iMode` to `sinx` and not sinx(t).

Comment: You should use `self.iMode is None` instead of `==`.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it is obvious that your attribute was set to `'sinx(t)'` (the string literal).

You should set it the function reference `sinx` instead, which is a callable.

However, as zhangyangu already said, in you example using `getattr()` is not needed. Maybe you really want to use a parameter (string reference) instead of the literal `'iMode'`?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, your `iMode` is a string. The `iMode` is not a method. There must be something wrong with your declaration. And in the class you can use `self.iMode`, no need to use `getattr`.

I think you may look for the function like `eval`.